# Android: How to change background color of a view in table layout base on conditions?

Tags: android

I've been Googling the whole morning but I still can't find the answer. Please help.

What I'm trying to achieve:

1. To show a table with checkboxes (default all unchecked) in every cell. I think table layout should be the way, unless there are other suggestions?
2. User can freely check/uncheck any of the checkboxes.
3. If all checkboxes for a given row (or column) are checked, change that row (or column) background color to red.

For example:

```
O = unchecked 
X = checked

Initially all the cells are white
O  O  O  O  O
O  O  O  O  O
O  O  O  O  O

User changed it to below, all the cells are still white
X  O  X  X  X
O  X  O  O  O
O  X  O  O  O

User changed it to below, all the cells with X will now change to red
X  X  X  X  X
O  X  O  O  O
O  X  O  O  O
```

I found examples that create table layout views programmatically, but I couldn't figure out how to refresh the views (to change the background color) by checking condition other than to redraw the whole thing again every time a condition is met.

Is there a way to bind a cell's background color to some array in code, so that when I change the array's value the background color changes dynamically?

Comment: What's wrong with just doing a complete redraw every time the user checks or unchecks a cell?

Comment: You're saying that a complete redraw is normal when working on Android UI? I'm perfectly fine if this is the only way. Because being accustomed to Microsoft WPF data binding, this seems a little hackish.. when I do a complete redraw I always have a feeling that I'm not doing it the right way, if you know what I mean.

Comment: I wouldn't call myself an expert on Android, but I can't think of another way of doing it. If you use a ListView, say, and log the times getView() is called you will find that each item is redrawn an enormous number of times as you scroll the list. If you only have 15 cells I wouldn't worry about it.